# How to create and inject multiple ServiceBusReceiver singletons similar to named ServiceBusClients when using Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azureservicebus

I am writing applications (Asp.net Web API / Worker Services) that use multiple `BackgroundServices` which listen to various Azure Service Bus queues and/or topics.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#reusing-factories-and-clients) recommends

> The Service Bus objects that interact with the service, such as ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusSender, ServiceBusReceiver, and ServiceBusProcessor, should be registered for dependency injection as singletons (or instantiated once and shared). [...]
> We recommend that you don't close or dispose these objects after sending or receiving each message.

Fair enough, so I added this to my startup code:

```
services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
{
    builder.AddServiceBusClient(myConnectionString);
});
```

But what should I do with the various `ServiceBusReceiver` instances? Without dependency injection, I would do:

```
ServiceBusReceiver receiverA = client.CreateReceiver("queue-a");
ServiceBusReceiver receiverB = client.CreateReceiver("queue-b");
ServiceBusReceiver receiverC = client.CreateReceiver("queue-c");
```

Do I have to create and register a separate singleton wrapper class for each of the `ServiceBusReceiver` instances?
Or is there an easier way similar to [named ServiceBusClients](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/best-practices-for-using-azure-sdk-with-asp-net-core/#configure-multiple-service-clients-with-different-names)?

*P.S.: I also have the analogous question for `ServiceBusSender` instances. In case that is somehow different in nature.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create wrappers a solution could be to register a delegate  in the dependency injection.

You start by defining a delegate that returns a ServiceBusReceiver based on a name :

```cs
public delegate ServiceBusReceiver ServiceBusReceiverResolver(string name);
```

Then you can register an implementation of the delegate that return the receiver related to the name

```cs
ServiceBusReceiver receiverA = client.CreateReceiver("queue-a");
ServiceBusReceiver receiverB = client.CreateReceiver("queue-b");
ServiceBusReceiver receiverC = client.CreateReceiver("queue-c");

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceBusReceiverResolver>(name => name switch
{
    "queue-a" => receiverA,
    "queue-b" => receiverB,
    "queue-C" => receiverC,
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown receiver {name}")
});
```

You now can inject the delegate into your services and use it to get the receiver you need :

```cs
public class MyService
{
    private readonly ServiceBusReceiver receiver;
    public MyService(ServiceBusReceiverResolver resolver)
    {
        receiver = resolver("queue-b");
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you address disposal in your solution when just using a delegate?  Are you just relying on `ServiceBusClient.DisposeAsync()` to do the job? In your example the `ServiceBusReceiver.DisposeAsync()` is neither called explicitly nor implicitly by the dependency injection container. For the analogous sending scenario I came up with a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75615489/3760986) where I use a singleton wrapper class as a registry for created `ServiceBusSender` instances, mainly for the purpose of having a proper lifecycle management via `IAsyncDisposable`.