# How to create ServiceBusSender dynamically when using request-reply communication model via the ReplyTo message property in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azureservicebus, request-response

After [having looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602827/how-to-handle-servicebussessionreceiver-and-message-session-lifetimes-when-using) into a [message session based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions#request-response-pattern) request-reply pattern, I decided to implement a request-reply model that does NOT use message sessions, but solely relies on the `ReplyTo` and `CorrelationId` message properties as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads#message-routing-and-correlation):

> Simple request/reply: A publisher sends a message into a queue and expects a reply from the message consumer. To receive the reply, the publisher owns a queue into which it expects replies to be delivered. The address of that queue is expressed in the ReplyTo property of the outbound message. When the consumer responds, it copies the MessageId of the handled message into the CorrelationId property of the reply message and delivers the message to the destination indicated by the ReplyTo property.

Now, the problem is that when service A is receiving messages from multiple services B, C, D,... etc., it cannot know beforehand which queue name will be in the `ReplyTo` field. As a consequence, A must be able to create `ServiceBusSender` instances dynamically for being able to write reply messages to various queues.

This kind of goes against the [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#reusing-factories-and-clients) to create long-lasting `ServiceBusSender` instances:

> The Service Bus objects that interact with the service, such as ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusSender, ServiceBusReceiver, and ServiceBusProcessor, should be registered for dependency injection as singletons (or instantiated once and shared). [...] We recommend that you don't close or dispose these objects after sending or receiving each message.

So what's the best way do deal with the above conflictive requirements of dynamic vs. static `ServiceBusSender` instance creation when also considering dependency injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating `ServiceBusSender` instances on demand whose lifecycle will still be handled by the dependency injection container, one can use a threadsafe wrapper singleton that keeps track of all created senders.

Something like this:

```
public class UniversalServiceBusSender : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly ServiceBusClient _client;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ServiceBusSender> _senderRegistry = new ();

    public UniversalServiceBusSender(ServiceBusClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public Task SendMessageAsync(ServiceBusMessage message, string queueOrTopicName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var sender = _senderRegistry.GetOrAdd(queueOrTopicName, _client.CreateSender);
        return sender.SendMessageAsync(message, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        if (!_senderRegistry.IsEmpty)
        {
            var disposeTasks = _senderRegistry.Values.Select(sender => sender.DisposeAsync());
            foreach (var disposeTask in disposeTasks)
            {
                await disposeTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            _senderRegistry.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

During startup, the service registration would look like this:

```
services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
{
    builder.AddServiceBusClient(options.AzureServiceBus.ConnectionString);
});

services.AddSingleton<UniversalServiceBusSender>();
```

The `UniversalServiceBusSender` singleton can then be constructor-injected wherever needed.

Comment: Seems a reasonable approach to me.   You could do a `Task.WhenAll` when disposing and save the explicit loop.   You also may want to consider marking the object disposed before cleaning up and not allowing `SendMessageAsync` to be called when marked.   Otherwise, a race condition exists where a new sender could be added during disposal and may be overlooked.

Comment: @JesseSquire Thanks for the feedback. I tried `Task.WhenAll`, but it only seems to be applicable to `Task`s and not to `ValueTask`s. At least that's what my compiler and my googling told me. Any advice?

Comment: ValueTask has an "AsTask" method that you would add to your Select when passing to Task.WhenAll

Comment: I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689327/task-whenall-for-valuetask/63141544#63141544) which defines a `WhenAll` for `ValueTask`.

Comment: Nice solution, but why not use the IAzureClientFactory instead ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/dependency-injection?tabs=web-app-builder